Restart Connector Debezium For RDS Postgres
I have a debezium connector on top of a Postgres database. So far, so good.
Inside this database, I have a database with 10 tables in which debezium is connected. Additionally, the connector is sending events to Kafka.
If I want to restart the full load of just one of the tables, how do I do it? Or is there no such possibility and I have to redo the full load of all 10 tables?

i think you create separate connector for that table and exclude it in your current connector.

But if I do this, my cost increases because every time I need to do this, I will split my connector in two. I also believe that it is not good practice to create a connector just for one table.

Yes that's what i recommended, you can create a connector for all tables which you intending to perform occasional snapshots.
